# Need to close all new window opened by my application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have tried to close the new window by `Window.close()` this works for current tab close but I need to close all the new tabs opened by my application
                `var newwindow=null;
                function NewWindow(mypage,myPagename)
                {
                    params  = 'width='+screen.width;
                    params += ', height='+screen.height;
                    params += ', top=0, left=0';
                    params +=', scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes';
                    newwindow=window.open(mypage,myPagename, params);
                    if (window.focus)
                    {
                        newwindow.focus()
                    }
                    return false;
                }`

Shall we close the new window by having their name , if yes means how ???

Comment: Keep a reference to the windows you opened, eg `var windows = []; widows.push(window.open('foo.html'));`, then you can loop through that array and close each window by its reference. To give you any more detail I'd need to see how you're opening the windows and how you currently store the references to them

Comment: Hello @ Rory McCrossan for me I open new window in different && different modules as i like , so I cant maintain the "Global Array"  for my application , As like this I tried previously its not working , for me while logout I need to close all new tab opened by my application

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `window.open()` to a variable and then [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the window variable. Something like this:

`var testWindow = window.open("enter/your/url");
testWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', yourListenerFunction);`

Now when you want to close the window, you need to do this:

`testWindow.removeEventListener('loadstart', yourListenerFunction);
testWindow.close();`

> removeEventListener() method removes the event listener previously registered with addEventListener().

Comment: what's the purpose of `event listener` here?

Comment: Hello @shishir-anshuman for me I open new window in different && different modules, so I cant maintain the "Var" Test-window Globally for my application , As like this I tried previously its not working , for me while logout I need to close all new tab opened by my application